# Keeping User state when refreshing or changing the page in vuex

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, authentication, vuex

As you can see my user state is null at the beginning but when the user logs in, I need to user id for my action called **setFavoriteCrypto**

So I can retrieve the specific data that is related to the user connected but since vuex initialize the state every time there's a refresh of the page. the user becomes null

I know there's a package called persist state which is something I could work with.

But I would like to know if there's a different way of managing my user connected without depending on a package?

*I am using node.js as my backend for this app.*

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'
import axios from 'axios'

import router from '@/router'

const state = {
    localStorageToken: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || null,
    token: null,
    user: null,
    favoriteCrypto: []
}

const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.localStorageToken = token
        state.token = token
    },
    setUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
    setFavoritecrypto(state, crypto) {
        state.favoriteCrypto = crypto
    }
}

const actions = {
    setToken({commit}, token) {
        commit('setToken', token)
    },
    setUser({commit}, user) {
        commit('setUser', user)
    },
    setFavoriteCrypto({commit}, token) {
        if(state.user) {
            return Api().get('getuserfavoritescoins', {
                params: {
                    userId: state.user.id
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.data.coins)
            .then(cryptoFav => {
                commit('setFavoritecrypto', cryptoFav)
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("there's not user state")
        }
    },
    loginUser({commit}, payload) {
        return Api().post('login', payload)
        .then(response => {
            commit('setUser', response.data.user)
            commit('setToken', response.data.token)

            localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.data.token)

            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token

            router.push('/main').catch(e => {})
        })
    },
    logoutUser({commit, dispatch})  {
        localStorage.removeItem('user-token')

        commit('setUser', null)
        commit('setToken', null)

        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    }
}

const getters = {
    isAuthenticated: state => !!state.localStorageToken,
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge there are only 2 options you can choose from: persist the state in localstorage or retrieve it from your backend whenever the user hits refresh

Comment: thank you for replying.

How would you retrieve it from the backend without sending a specific parameters? Meaning, I would lose the user.state while refreshing so in my mind there isn't a proof that this IS the user connected?

Comment: Cookies. They persist so you'd just pass over your session-cookie and check on the backend if it's still valid.